# CORS header is being stripped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I recently implemented a Asp.Net WebApi and deployed it successfully. I included the Cors library so that this API can be used from any network.

First run through, it works correctly, I can see that the header is set and did a test on test-cors.org.

A colleague of mine, says that he does not get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, as if Chrome is stripping it out? When using a different browser, Firefox or Internet Explorer, the header is there.

Has anyone come across this before?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you google `chrome cors problem` there are several similar questions around.

Comment: Ok sure, but I can't find anything related to my issue. It works in my chrome, but not on my colleagues. We both use the test-cors.org site.

Comment: It could be a chrome setting preventing cors maybe?